# Accidentally switched to incorrect version of libc, can't update back

Tags: linux, glibc

While doing a CTF I downloaded a deb containing a version of libc (ubuntu 2.28). I tried to extract the binary, but accidentally uninstalled my libc, and replaced it with the wrong one. Now I can't run any programs, and apt won't upgrade back to the correct version, because the postinstall scripts depend on GLIBC_2.29. Is there any way to fix?

Comment: Yes, you can fix it, but we need a bit more information. It seems you can boot and run `apt-get` can you add to you question the command you are using to upgrade and the error messages you get?

Comment: In the end as it was in a virtual machine I rolled back to a month old snapshot and backed up my important files.